# port forwarding from wireguard interface to another host with iptables

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, wireguard

I have two servers that I can access one of them via wireguard.
I have a service that listen on 4559 port on the second server.
how can I port forward to second server via iptables.

```
[laptop]                         [server1]                 [server2]
10.10.0.1 (wireguard) -------> 10.10.0.2:4559 --------> 192.168.1.20:4559
```

Comment: Why do you want to NAT? Just route normally.

Comment: how shuold id do it?

Answer (score 1):

To forward TCP port 4559 from your WireGuard interface on server1 to server2, add this to the `[Interface]` section of server1's WireGuard config:

```
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i %i -p tcp --dport 4559 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.20
PreUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o %i -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i %i -p tcp --dport 4559 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.20
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING ! -o %i -j MASQUERADE
```

Replace `-p tcp` with `-p udp` if it's UDP port 4559 you're trying to forward.

That will work just fine to access server2 from the laptop as `10.10.0.2:4559`; but your particular scenario sounds a lot like the common "point-to-site" access pattern -- with the laptop being the remote "point", and server1 providing access to a larger "site". With that pattern, you normally would either configure the router at the site to route your WireGuard subnet (like `10.10.0.0/24`) directly via server1 (no NAT), or you would set up SNAT on server1 to masquerade packets from WireGuard to the site.

With either of those point-to-site approaches, you would access port 4559 on server2 from the laptop as `192.168.1.20:4559` (just like if the laptop was physically on the site's LAN). Here's a good overview of your [WireGuard point-to-site routing options](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/04/wireguard-point-to-site-routing/), with links to step-by-step guides if you want to further explore those options.

Comment: I still can't access service with telnet.

Comment: Ah, you're probably also going to need to masquerade the packets forwarded from server1 to server2 -- I edited my answer to include an additional `MASQUERADE` iptables rule.

Comment: still don't work

Comment: 1) run `sudo iptables -S` on server1 to list your active iptables rules to see if you have other rules that are blocking access; 2) run `sudo nft list ruleset` on server1 to see if you have nftables rules that are blocking access; 3) run `ping 10.10.0.2` on the laptop to verify that you can connect to server1 through WireGuard; 4) run `telnet 192.168.1.20 4559` on server1 to verify that you can connect to server2